# Is there a way to use the index to avoid a filesort when OR is used in MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, filesort

I have the following query and the following 2 indexes, but I am still getting a filesort.  Is there a way to optimize this further so that I avoid the filesort, or do I just need to live with it?

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE row1 > '0' OR row2 = '1' ORDER BY id DESC
```

Indexes:

> row1
>
> row2,id

EXPLAIN output:

> Using sort_union(row1,row2_id);
> Using where; Using filesort

Comment: What datatype are the columns row1 and row2

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY ROW2,ID or add an index on ID.

Comment: There is an index on id, it is the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Just add index like (id, row1, row2).

This index will work, because rows in it will be pre-sorted and mySQL will only need to select the satisfying lines.

Moreover, sort_union() index merging is not THAT good optimization for mySQL anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit late for answering but i want to say that, using "or" probably causing that problem. You can try using union with two different queries.

Comment: He sorts the result set by `id` but there's no index on `id` (or a compound one where `id` is the first column). That's more likely the reason for file sort, IMHO.

Comment: may be a combined index like "row1,row2,id" can do the job.

Comment: Some other index possibly, yes. I was thinking more along the lines of changing the index on `row1` to one on `row1, id` or adding a separate index on `id`, but then I'm not really an expert on indexes. Although this seems a simple case, I would have to test and compare before pronouncing my judgement.